# How to parse Java object using Gson and get values of each element?

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing, gson

```
title = u.getOrganizations();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonItems = gson.toJson(title);  
System.out.println(jsonItems);
if(jsonItems.length() >0 && !jsonItems.equalsIgnoreCase(null)){
    JSONArray jObj = new JSONArray(jsonItems);
    System.out.println(jObj.toString());
}
```

**Current Output:**

```
[{"name":"ABCD","title":"Test Specialist","primary":true,"customType":"Work"}]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
name: ABCD
title: Test Specialist
primary: true
customType: Work
```

This is new to me, tried online resources was not able to get what i intended to, your help is greatly appreciated.. thanks!

Comment: Do you have any problem in printing contents of jObj ??

Comment: outputting jObj correctly and handling null data, but i am having difficulty in getting only title from this object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json string is a Array with one element

String jsonString  = your json

```
            JsonArray jsonArray= new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonArray();
            JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonArray.get(0);
            System.out.println("title :"+jsonObject.get("title"));
```

etc....